# Spring Batch - simple json api batching

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

I need to get the data from REST JSON API (every 24h) which returns a lot of data in array (lets say 500MB). Now, in order to do that I was thinking of using Spring Batch. I would process JSON in chunks (say 1000 records per chunk) and then index it in bulk in elastic search. The problem is that all those spring batch support classes (`JobLauncher`, `JobExplorer`, `JobRepository`, ...) look too much to me. I suppose I would need just some retryable runnable that would use `JsonBufferedReaderFactory` and `FlatFileItemReader` like so:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<SomeObj> ffir(){
    FlatFileItemReader<SomeObj> ffir = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    ffir.setBufferedReaderFactory(new JsonBufferedReaderFactory());
    ffir.setLineMapper(new JsonLineMapper<>(SomeObj.class));
    try {
        ffir.setResource(new UrlResource("http://localhost:8080/cars/759"));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ffir;
}
```

where reader factory is:

```
public class JsonBufferedReaderFactory implements BufferedReaderFactory {
    @Override
    public BufferedReader create(Resource resource, String encoding) throws IOException {
        return new JsonBufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream(), encoding));
    }

    private final class JsonBufferedReader extends BufferedReader {
        private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        private final JsonFactory factory = mapper.getFactory();
        private final JsonParser parser;
        private ObjectNode node;

        JsonBufferedReader(Reader in) throws IOException {
            super(in);
            parser = factory.createParser(in);
            if (parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Expected an array");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String readLine() throws IOException {
            JsonToken nextToken = parser.nextToken();
            if (nextToken == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
                node = mapper.readTree(parser);
                return node.toString();
            }
            if (nextToken == JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
                return null;
            }
            throw new IllegalStateException("Expected start of object or end of array of objects");
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            super.close();
            parser.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there possibility to run this use-case without all this additional classes that seems like overkill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to take a look into [Spring WebFlux](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#spring-webflux). It provides a Reactive `WebClient` with the `bodyToFlux`. So, you big JSON will be processed via on demand back-pressure manner.